# How manual mock methods in ES6 class by using mock file in __mocks__ folder?

Tags: mocking, jestjs

I'm trying manual mock method in ES6 class, by creating manual mock file in `__mock__`folder. But mock file not work at all. Here's my project:

```
├── __mocks__
│   └── MockTestDependency.js
├── MockTestDependency.js
└── MockTest.test.js
```

./MockTestDependency.js:

```
export default class MockTestDependency {
    addAction(value1, value2) {
        return value1 + value2
    }
}
```

./__mocks__/MockTestDependency.js:

```
export default {
    addAction: jest.fn((value1, value2) => {
        return value1 + value2 + 1
    })
}
```

./MockTest.test.js:

```
import MockTestDependency from "./MockTestDependency"

beforeAll(() => {
    jest.mock('./MockTestDependency')
})

describe('mock test', () => {
    it('first case', () => {
        let mockTestDependency = new MockTestDependency()
        expect(mockTestDependency.addAction(1, 2)).toBe(4)
    })
})
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jest.mock('./MockTestDependency')` should be called before `beforeAll`, just after imports.

It will be hoisted to the top of code block and in fact called before any imports (which is necessary to work). When it's inside `beforeAll` it's called after external dependency is already loaded.